# Outlook New email Envelope Icon disappears before new emails are red

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-office-2016

We have a user that when they get a new email has the usual prompts and notifications. However when they click on the Outlook inbox or another email that has already been read, the envelope icon disappears.

I've already looked in the settings and can't find anyway to extend or change the amount of time that the envelope stays visible.

Most posts I've found are trying to either trying to remove or add the notification. The notification is there and stays until you interact with the inbox.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the yellow envelope icon in the taskbar when new message arrives? I tested in my Outlook 2016 but cannot reproduce the issue. It won't disappear until I click and read the new mail in Inbox. Have you tried testing in Outlook safe mode (outlook /safe) to see if the issue remains?

Comment: I have not, unfortunately the user was unable to allow us access to the machine yesterday and I'm now off site. However I will try this when next on site. @YukiSun